# Planet rings transparency goes wrong

Tags: displacement, distort

[image: pic01]

I am doing solar system, and maybe it's because the scale and distances are big, but do you guys know how to do the rings so they are just transparent and not bending the light of an object, so it looks distorted?

I followed these tutorials([tut01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfC-oSKSuUQ), [tut02](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQVoHhCx6kI)) how to do it, but the result is always like in the picture above.

Comment: You are supposed to plug the texture's alpha channel into the mix shader's "Fac" socket instead of the transpareny shader. You can see it in the tut01 video.

Comment: FFeller, I did that at the beginning but in that case the rings were not transparent at all, so I change it a little.

Comment: Now I see, your texture doesn't have alpha channel at all because it's jpg. Then plug the color channel to the fac socket. If the transparent parts are white swap the input shaders of the mix shader, if they are black, then keep their position.

Comment: Can you upload your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6141" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6141/) I tried to do it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please upload your texture file too because you didn't packed it.

Comment: Here you go. Texture for Planet - https://ibb.co/N6tv4cL and rings - https://ibb.co/FJyFT20

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/408rlmK It looks you were right. In this giant distance the transparent shader acts like it has an index of refraction, but it has not. I never seen this problem before. May be you have to find an other way to render your video. Best wishes.

Comment: Yeah, I read about that blender doesn't handle "big" projects to well. But I hoped that there is some way around it. Anyway thank you for your help.